# Commit changes with ankhsvn

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I have this problem with **ankhsvn**:

[image: im1]

i have the solution up to date , but not its unique project . When i try to commit i got this error

[image: im2]

when i click into `Show changes` i have some changes in a temporary file `integration_finale.csproj`

[image: im3]

So, What are the reasons of this error? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `csproj` file is not a temp file. It governs your project set-up and settings for references, paths, build details etc.

From how it appears this conflict can (probably) use local as it appears the rest of the file is correct (at least from the image). It appears that the change is just that the `SpecificVersion` flag for he reference has been changed to the default setting.

Now you should backup this file and confirm the rest of the file is correct. If you corrupt this file you will have to rebuild the project file (csproj).

Comment: *.csproj files are also very prone to conflicts if 2 revisions added files independently.

Answer (score 2):

- 'Clean' solution via AnkhSVN and get update again
- if above does not works then I would suggest you to take backup of your current .csproj file. Then update the file to latest commit version on svn. After which you can merge code and commit your changes.
- better use TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 1):

I use **ankhsvn**, and I know that it has a few bugs. To diagnose (and better handle conflicts too) this kind of problems I use also [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html).